# Can't mount exfat flash drive

Tags: mount, usb-drive

when I plug in the flash drive, or try to mount it, it says

> ```
> "Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/dejel/76E8-CACF: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/dejel/76E8-CACF"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'"
> ```

how do I access this flash drive? it has no issues with windows computers.
nothing on it yet, so if that'll work & help, I'll reformat it. Flash drive was 1.9 TB & exFAT format.

Comment: Your USB stick is probably formatted as [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT); you may want to install packages `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451364/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu-14-04/451376#451376), before trying the USB stick again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reformatted my flash drive from exFAT format to NTFS.

*note: NTFS does not work for larger than 2.0 TB, thankfully mine was only 1.9*

for those using usb storage devices that have more than 2.0 TB it'd be best to use the method dogoncouch suggested

> exfat filesystem utils are not installed by default on Ubuntu, but it is
> easy to install them. Run this:
>
> > sudo apt install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
>
> Then it should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

exfat filesystem utils are not installed by default on Ubuntu, but it is easy to install them. Run this:

`sudo apt install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

Then it should work fine.

Comment: That probably would have worked, but I found my own solution.

Comment: Most usb thumb drives use FAT32, so that might be a good idea for a format. NTFS might not be readable on all systems (Apple, etc), but FAT32 is widely supported. exfat on a thumb drive is odd, I usually only see exfat on SD cards.

Comment: that may be true, however I will likely only be using my laptop & windows computers when using this flash-drive.